# Pagination issue when working with filters

Tags: php, mysql

I have a pagination class with buildTrail function to display pages number.

For searching the db, this class is working great.

If i'm searching for "intel", the second page link will be `"http://localhost/search/intel/pg/2".`
The problem occures when i try to filter the results .EX: "`http://localhost/search/intel/type/ssd`" so the links for paging will display : ex"`http://localhost/search/intel/type/ssd/intel/type/ssd/pg/2`"

```
function buildTrail($param = ""){
    // $cur_page = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $link = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $link_array = explode('/', $link);
    //$count = count($link_array);
    $pagename = $link_array[1];
    // echo $magename;
    if(is_array($param)){
        foreach($param as $a => $b){
            if($a != "page"){
                $url .= $pagename."/".$b;
            }
        }

    } else {
        $url = $param;
    }

    $trail = "";
    if($this->getPages() > 1){
        if($this->getFrom() > 1){
            $trail .= "<a href='" . WEBSITE . "/". $url . "/pg/" . $this->getPrevious()."'>&laquo;</a>\n ";
        }

        if($this->getFrom() < 10 && $this->getPages() > 10){
            for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++){
                $trail .= "<a class='". ($i == $this->getFrom() ? "selected" : "links") . "' href='" . WEBSITE . "/".$url."/pg/" . $i ."'>" . $i . "</a>\n ";
            }
        } elseif($this->getFrom() < 10 && $this->getPages() < 10){
            for ($i = 1; $i <= $this->getPages(); $i++){
                $trail .= "<a class='". ($i == $this->getFrom() ? "selected" : "links") . "' href='" . WEBSITE . "/".$url."/pg/" . $i ."'>" . $i . "</a>\n ";
            }
        }elseif ($this->getFrom() >= 10 && $this->getFrom() <= ($this->getPages() - 5) ){
            for ($i = ($this->getFrom() - 5); $i <= ($this->getFrom() + 5); $i ++){
                $trail .= "<a  class='". ($i == $this->getFrom() ? "selected" : "links") . "' href='" . WEBSITE . "/".$url."/pg/" . $i ."'>" . $i . "</a>\n ";
            }
        } else {            
            for ($i = ($this->getPages() - 10); $i <= $this->getPages(); $i ++){
                $trail .= "<a  class='". ($i == $this->getFrom() ? "selected" : "links") . "' href='" . WEBSITE . "/".$url."/pg/" . $i ."'>" . $i . "</a>\n ";
            }
        }
        if($this->getFrom() < $this->getPages()){
        $trail .= "<a href='" . WEBSITE . "/".$url."/pg/" . $this->getNext()."'>&raquo;</a>\n ";
        }
    }

    return $trail;
}
```

Comment: Validation is, in my opinion, the first step in being a good programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options -Indexes 
Options +FollowSymLinks
<Files .htaccess>
deny from all
</Files>

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/pg/([0-9]+)(/)?$ search.php?page=$2&q=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/sort/(.*)/$ search.php?q=$1&sort=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/sort/(.*)$ search.php?q=$1&sort=$2 [NC,L]
```